# I can't setState with a useContext hook from an API response

Tags: reactjs, state

I cannot set the state of a useContext hook with the response of an API. However, I can console.log the JSON response? This code is in the App.js file. In addition, I have this code snippet used elsewhere in the project and it is able to save the state to a useState hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/americanfootball_nfl/scores/?daysFrom=1&apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
        } else {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
    .then((jsonifiedResponse) => {
        setMainScoresList(jsonifiedResponse);
        console.log(jsonifiedResponse);
      })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, [])
```

Comment: Is `App` component wrapped by the context provider? (context provider must be higher than `App` in the component tree).

Answer (score 0):

everything looks fine to me, but honestly I usually use axios, so I might be over looking something. I highly suggest it. It doesnt take alot of time. good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).